# zip choices of formfield with other data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a table where I would like to show some data in first two columns, and a radio choice in the last one so that a user can choose one of the rows.

I can loop through the choices of a field with radio select widget like that:

```
{% for choice in form.user_choice %}
    <td>{{ choice }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

But how can I get the `choices` as a set of inputs in `get_context_data` of a django view so that I can zip them with some other data.

If I do something like that:

```
 frm = self.get_form()
 return {'data':zip(SomeDataListHere, frm.fields['user_choice'].choices)}
```

it returns my `SomeDataListHere` zipped with the list of tuples (which are choices initially). So I definitely miss something here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well, the answer was very obvious. instead of using

```
frm.fields['my_field_name']
```

I have to use

```
frm['my_field_name']
```

and then I can zip this safely with all other data in `get_context_data` and render it on the template:

```
frm = self.get_form()
f = frm['my_field_name']
return {'data': zip(some_other_data, f)}
```